# How to view new LWC?

Tags: lwc-oss, lightning-web-components

I want to play around with the new Lightning Web Component announced earlier today. I have Node.JS downloaded and I'm running a local server, but I'm unable to see anything at the address '0.0.0.0:3001'

[image: /LWC server]

Does anyone know what the path name is?
I dug around in documentation, but don't see anything on the github page/sf documentation.

https://github.com/muenzpraeger/lwc-create-app

https://lwc.dev/guide/install

Comment: I'd guess there is some config missing because you'd generally see one of "localhost", "127.0.0.1" or your machine's currently allocated IP address for local servers... NB: this is a general comment, I haven't tried this with lwc.dev myself.

Comment: @muenzpraeger is on holiday today. If no one else helps you out, I'm sure he can by Monday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webpack devserver defaults to the special IP Mask 0.0.0.0 in the lwc-create-app default config which is kind of a placeholder for all IPv4 addresses assigned to the machine but its not routeable in the sense of accessing it directly

As stated by Phil you could either use http://127.0.0.1:3001/ or http://localhost:3001/ to access the server which represents the loopback address to your local machine

Comment: That was it, thank you!